# The context you are using comes from the widget above the BlocProvider. I use Dialog

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

Faced a problem when adding Bloc. I use Counter which is in `Dialog` and do everything through Block but for some reason I got this error (see below). I did the same before and there was no error. I do not fully understand what the error is connected with and how to solve it correctly. I have a `HomePage` class in which I declare `Bloc` and in which the `HomeBody` class is nested, and in this class there is a button for opening `Dialog` (`FilterDialog`) and in this `Dialog` I have a `Counter` that I did through `Bloc`. I will be grateful for help.

**home page**

```
class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocProvider<CounterCubit>(
      create: (context) => CounterCubit(),
      child: Scaffold(
        extendBodyBehindAppBar: true,
        appBar: LogoAppBar(
            buttonIcon: SvgPicture.asset(constants.Assets.burgerMenu)),
        body: const HomeBody(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**home body**

```
class HomeBody extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomeBody({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;

    return Container(
      width: size.width,
      height: size.height,
      decoration: const BoxDecoration(
        image: DecorationImage(
          image: AssetImage('assets/images/background/main_background.png'),
          fit: BoxFit.cover,
        ),
      ),
      child: _child(context, size),
    );
  }

  Widget _child(context, Size size) => Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 121, right: 24),
        child: Align(
          alignment: Alignment.topRight,
          child: GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {
              showDialog(
                context: context,
                builder: (context) {
                  return const FilterDialog();
                },
              );
            },
            child: Container(
              height: 40,
              width: 50,
              decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.amber,
              ),
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              child: const Text('Dialog'),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      );
}
```

**FilterDialog**

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Dialog(
        insetPadding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 100, left: 24, right: 24),
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(24))),
        child: Container(
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
          decoration: const BoxDecoration(
            color: constants.Colors.greyDark,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(24)),
          ),
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(21, 38, 21, 24),
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                PriceCounter(title: 'From'),
              ]
```

**price counter**

```
    class PriceCounter extends StatelessWidget {
  final String title;

  const PriceCounter({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final CounterCubit cubit = BlocProvider.of<CounterCubit>(context);

    return Column(
      children: [
        BlocBuilder<CounterCubit, CounterState>(
          builder: (context, state) => InputField(
              price: state.countValue.toString(),
              textStyle: constants.Styles.normalBookTextStyleWhite),
        ),
        Row(
          children: [
            IconButton(
              onPressed: () => cubit.increment(),
              icon: SvgPicture.asset(constants.Assets.plus),
              constraints: const BoxConstraints(),
              padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
            ),
            Text('Test', style: constants.Styles.smallLtStdTextStyleWhite),
            IconButton(
              onPressed: () => cubit.decrement(),
              icon: SvgPicture.asset(constants.Assets.minus),
              constraints: const BoxConstraints(),
              padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
            ),
          ],
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

**counter state**

```
class CounterState {
  final double countValue;
  const CounterState({required this.countValue});
}
```

**counter cubit**

```
class CounterCubit extends Cubit<CounterState> {
  CounterCubit() : super(const CounterState(countValue: 0.13));

  void increment() => emit(CounterState(countValue: state.countValue + 0.1));

  void decrement() => emit(CounterState(countValue: state.countValue - 0.1));
}
```

> The following assertion was thrown building PriceCounter(dirty):
> BlocProvider.of() called with a context that does not contain a CounterCubit.
>
> ```
>     No ancestor could be found starting from the context that was passed to BlocProvider.of<CounterCubit>().
>
>     This can happen if the context you used comes from a widget above the BlocProvider.
>
>     The context used was: PriceCounter(dirty)
> ```
>
> The relevant error-causing widget was PriceCounter
> lib\…\widgets\filter_dialog.dart:233 When the exception was thrown,
> this was the stack

[image]

Comment: How are your two code blocks and build methods connected? I can see no PriceCounter in your code sample with the BlocProvider. What is HomeBody?

Comment: HomeBody используется для главных страниц в том классе, где хранятся все виджеты, то есть все, что относится к разметке страниц.

Comment: I have updated the code. There in HomeBody I have a FilterDialog inside which is a PriceCounter

Comment: I added the code sequentially for convenience, please have a look

Comment: I fix the error, wait to my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, your **FilterDialog** cannot find the **CounterCubit** provider, since *showDialog* is a bit tricky about it, so you have to re-supply your **CounterCubit** to **FilterDialog** in this way:

```
  Widget _child(context, Size size) => Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 121, right: 24),
        child: Align(
          alignment: Alignment.topRight,
          child: GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {
              showDialog(
                context: context,
                builder: (context) {
                  return BlocProvider.value( // in this way
                    value: CounterCubit(),
                    child: FilterDialog(),
                  );
                },
              );
            },
            child: Container(
              height: 40,
              width: 50,
              decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.amber,
              ),
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              child: const Text('Dialog'),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      );
}
```

With **BlocProvider.value** you do not create a Bloc, but only assign to its child the bloc that you have already created in *HomePage*.

That should work, but if for some reason you are going to use this **CounterCubit** in another page and you don't want to use **BlocProvider.value** again, I strongly suggest that you make it global, in other words that you provide the **CounterCubit** in all your application in this way :

```
class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocProvider(
      create: (context) => CounterCubit(), // here
      child: MaterialApp(
        title: 'Material App',
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        home: const HomePage(), 
      ),
    );
  }

}
```

With this, now every application will be able to get the context of your **CounterCubit**.

With both codes, one with the **BlocProvider.value** or without it and using it global, it works.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help and for explaining.